# Fading specific CSS/JS Popup when opening/closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup, fade

The following code snippet shows how I made popups with CSS and JS. Is there any chance to let it fade when opening/closing it, without changing the way I used to work, I mean just popping up the box by changing its display style?

```
function lightbox_open(){
    window.scrollTo(100,500);
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'; 
}

function lightbox_close(){
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

[.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

```
function lightbox_open(){
    window.scrollTo(100,500);
    $('#light,#fade').fadeIn();
}
```

[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```
function lightbox_close(){
       $('#light,#fade').fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use either use jQuery to do the fading `$().fadeIn()` or use CSS3 animations if you want to stick to bare JS. In the latter case, set the opacity to 0 by default and change it to 1 via Javascript. You need to add this to your stylesheet:

```
selector {
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `fadein()` on open and `fadeout()` on close, but if you want to do it with pure javascript, i recommend reading this [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L107). they did it it wonderfully.